# Update query for three tables?

Tags: mysql

I have to pass a mysqli update query. Following are the three different tables with the situation.
I have a `user_table` with columns

```
user_id
user_email
```

I have a `webpage_table` with columns

```
webpage_id
first_webpage
second_webpage
```

I have a `user_data_table` with only columns

```
user_id
webpage_id as foreign key
```

Now I have to update the values of `webpage_table` where the `user_email="johndoe@xyz.com"`....

What will be my update `mysqli_query()` for the above situation...I tried but i'm not able to go any further of where condition.... Below is my attempt

```
UPDATE `webpage_table` SET `first_webpage`='xyz', `second_webpage`='xyz' 
WHERE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an updated  based on join
with the related  table

```
UPDATE `webpage_table` 
INNER JOIN user_data_table d on u.user_id = d.user_id 
      and `webpage_table`.webpage_id = d.webpage_id 
INNER JOIN user_table u.user_email="johndoe@xyz.com"
SET `first_webpage`='xyz',
   `second_webpage`='xyz'
```

Comment: will this ans be the exact query statement.... ?

Comment: i don't understand your comment ..

Comment: I got this error @scaisEdge ...You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.user_email="johndoe@xyz.com" SET `first_webpage`='xyz', `second_webpage`='xyz at line 1.

Comment: answer  updated ..  missing closing single quote after  second xyz